# EC2 Instance connectivity with diff region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a set of instances in Oregon region and my jenkin server in California. How do i connect instances with jenikins server with their private IPs. I am not running Instances all time. I can easily connect with public IPS when instances are up running. But I dont want to change IPs each time when i restart the instances. Alternatives to permanent connection would be helpful to me.

-Thanks

Comment: Hi Guru, if the response below answered your question please upvote and accept it. That's the ServerFault's way to say thank you for the time and effort someone took to help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You’ve got a couple of options:

- Assign **Elastic IPs** to the instances. EIPs are permanent and don’t change when you shut down/ restart the instances. So there will be no need to keep updating the IPs and you can also lock down the *Security Groups* because you’ll have known and permanent set of IPs. Note that there is a small cost for idle EIPs.
- Set up **Inter-region VPC Peering** if your VPCs have non-overlapping IP ranges. That way the instances can talk over their private IP addresses.
- Set up **VPN** between the regions. Probably an overkill for your situation as it will cost you more to either run the VGWs (VPN Gateways) or dedicated VPN EC2 Instances.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Note also that a VGW can't be used on both sides of a single VPN connection.  The other side must be something else (e.g. running on an instance if the other side is also inside AWS) because VGWs always expect the peer to be the one to initiate the connection -- they never initiate.

Comment: A bit more detail - an elastic IP is a good option to get a static IP, but it costs $0.005c/h when not used - that's $0.12 per day or $3.60 per month. VPC peering doesn't cost anything and allows connectivity via private IPs, so in this case may be the best option. VPN not really practical for reasons Michael outlined. PrivateLink is another option which I mention just for completeness, but isn't suitable in this case - it has an hourly cost.